# relative path to public folder leads to 404 not found for css file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have this link to a css file in my index.html:

```
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

the link points to a directory in my public/directory.

When I navigate to the root url of my app, everything is fine.

But when I navigate to another url manually (through the browser adress bar- (i.e. /session-info). The file is not loaded.

```
GET http://localhost:4200/session-info/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems like the relative path is messed up when starting from another URL. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a / at the begging of the css.

```
<link href="/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to add "./" in front of you file path. For example my css is located in this order "PROJECT>app>css>index.css" so my href would look like this.

> href="./app/css/index.css"

All and all you should have something like this....

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/css/index.css">
```